# Matrix representation needed

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose $B$ is an $N\times N$ matrix and $V$ is an $N\times 1$ vector.

I need to find a matrix representation for $V$:

$V_k = \sum_{j}B_{kj}^4 + 2\sum_{i\neq j}\sum_{j}B_{ki}^2B_{kj}^2$

Previously, I asked a somewhat similar question here: [Need to find matrix formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928901/need-to-find-matrix-formulation) and I can't find the answer of this one either.

Comment: What do you mean by $B^4_{kj}$? Is it the components of the 4th power of the matrix $(B^4)_{kj}$, or the 4th power of the components of the matrix $(B_{kj})^4$? Are you multiplying matrices or numbers?

Comment: 4th power of the components of matrix B $(B_{kj})^4$, I am multiplying numbers

Answer (score 0):

For typing convenience, define $$A=\big(B\odot B\big)$$ where $\odot$ represents the elementwise/Hadamard product.

Then the vector can be written in matrix notation as 
$$\eqalign{
 v &= (A\odot A)\,e + \big(2Ae\big)\odot\big(Ae-{\rm diag}(A)\big) \cr
}$$ where $e$ is the vector whose elements are all equal to unity.